# Laravel many-to-many query controller

Tags: php, laravel, api, http

So i have a `films` table and a `conversations` table and a pivot table `film_conversation`

**Film** (`films`)

```
'id'
'filmable_id',
'filmable_type',
```

**Conversation** (`conversations`)

```
'id'
'last_message_id'
```

**FilmConversation** (`film_conversation`)

```
'film_id'
'conversation_id'
```

I am wanting to create a `GET` request to grab all of the conversations that belong to that specific film, I have this query but unsure if I am grabbing it correctly and how would I write whats being returned in the response?

**ConversationController:**

```
/**
 * 
 */
public function conversations()
{
    $this->user = Auth::user();

    $film = Film::whereHas('conversations', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('id');
    })->get();

    return $film;
}
```

I have an additional question, should you directly include this query into the request method or split it out into a private method and include it in to increase readability and clutter of the call? what would be the best practice? It's an endpoint I'm exposing for the front end.

Comment: first of all, you're not using the authenticated user, second you're returning a collection of `films` that has any conversation, the query constraint isn't doing anything and you can just access `$film->conversations` to get the collection

Comment: Do you mind adding an example so i can understand what you mean?

Comment: `Film::whereHas('conversations')->first()->conversations`

Comment: yes, the conversations for the first film it found that has conversations

Comment: Okay other than modifying this query, removing the query constraint and adding your suggestion should this method in the controller then return what i need if i was to write a phpunit test for it?

Comment: uhh, you would have to pass the film ID for it, I'll write an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201842/discussion-between-bwinnyz-and-saly-3301).

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you're not using the authenticated user, second, you're returning a collection of films that has any conversation, the query constraint isn't doing anything and you can just access `$film->conversations` to get the collection

```php
public function conversations($id)
{
    // Get all conversations for a specified film
    return Film::find($id)->conversations;
    // Get all conversations in all films that have a conversation
    $films = Film::whereHas('conversations')->with('conversations')->get();
    $conversations = $films->flatMap->conversations;
    return $conversations;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hey thanks, that does help, do you know how i would serialize to json this answer you gave me?

Comment: It's already serialized to JSON by default, Laravel does that for you automatically

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param Film $film
 * @return Collection|Conversations[]
 */
public function conversations(Film $film)
{
    return $film->conversations;
}
```

in route file

```
Route::get('conversations/{film}');
```

this code will return json representation of conversations models collection https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json

or it return 404 if film id not exist.